# SOAP web services from AS3, without Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, soap

What's the best library/package/class out there for calling SOAP web services from ActionScript 3, without using the Flex framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to use the flex libraries? From what I understand using only the components you need into your application should not cause you any performance issues.

However take a look at: http://alducente.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/web-service-in-as3-release-10/

I'm not sure if it is the best, but it has been recommended to e by one of my co-workers.

Comment: Thanks, the alducente stuff seems like it can work for me. A somewhat later version can be found here: http://labs.alducente.com/gophr/

Answer (score 3):

Suggested reading:
Advanced ActionScript 3 with Design Patterns
by Joey Lott and Danny Patterson
Go to chapter 15 for a better and complete solution.

My example code:

```
private var xmlResults:XML = new URLLoader;
private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();


public function fErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
   trace("xml failed!");
        }


//when the "loader" event object finishes the loading of the xml file, run other needed functions to process the data 
private function fLoaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {

   trace("xml loaded!!"); //jwt testing
   var result2:XML = new XML(urlLoader.data); // loads the xml file data into the xml object
   xmlResults = result2; //have the global xml object equal the current data loaded xml object 
   result2 = null; // dont need current xml object any more so erase it

   fParseXML(0); //process the first set of records from the xml object
   trace("found xml" + xmlResults.toString()); 
        } 


public function fParseXML(intAddNum:Number):void{
   //create variables to store the record info
   //
   var envelope:XML = xmlResults; //XML(urlLoader.data);
   var soap:Namespace = envelope.namespace("soap");
   var responseN:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.domain.com/school/ServiceCollege");
   var resultL:XMLList = envelope.soap::Body.responseN::HelloTestResponse.responseN::HelloTestResult;

   var strTest:String;
   //if only one response field will be return by the web service
   strTest = resultL; 
   //do something like this if multiple  response feilds will be returned
   //strTest = resultL.response::schoolName.toString(); 
   trace("parsing:" + strTest);
   trace("done loading:");
  }


 public function fBeginRequest():void{
  var strXMLDataRequest:String
  var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
  urlRequest.contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
  urlRequest.method = "POST";
  urlRequest.url = "http://www.domain.com/school/serviceCollege.asmx";  
  var soapAction:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://www.domain.com/school/ServiceCollege/HelloTest");
  urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(soapAction);
  strXMLDataRequest = "&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"&gt;";
   strXMLDataRequest = strXMLDataRequest + "&lt;soap:Body&gt;";
   strXMLDataRequest = strXMLDataRequest + "&lt;HelloTest xmlns=\"http://www.domain.com/school/ServiceCollege\" /&gt;";
   strXMLDataRequest = strXMLDataRequest + "&lt;/soap:Body&gt;";
   strXMLDataRequest = strXMLDataRequest + "&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;";
    urlRequest.data =  new XML(strXMLDataRequest);
     urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
      urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, fErrorHandler); //add the event to the "loader" object
      urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fLoaderCompleteHandler); //add the event to the "loader" object
 }
```

Soap Request:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
  &lt;soap:Body&gt;
    &lt;HelloTest xmlns="http://www.domain.com/school/ServiceCollege" /&gt;
  &lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;
```

Soap Response:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
  &lt;soap:Body&gt;
    &lt;HelloTestResponse xmlns="http://www.domain.com/school/ServiceCollege">
      &lt;HelloTestResult&gt;string&lt;/HelloTestResult&gt;
    &lt;/HelloTestResponse&gt;
  &lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-flex-webservice-component-in.html) very useful.
Its a good tip in general: add a swc to enable Flex classes in flash.